# Reading 2-line input Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've finished writing a Haskell program but I have troubles with the I/O and Main parts of it. I want to read input of the following format:

```
10 3
1 4 8
```

The first and second numbers are Ints, and the numbers of the second line should be made into an integer list, [Int]. The length of the list is equal to the second number on the first line.

I have the following code to read one Int at a time, however, it can only get it to work for the first line of input.

```
getInt :: IO Int
getInt = do
    l <- getLine
    return (read l)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have a look at the `words` function - something like `map read . words` should work for you

Comment: BTW: I am a bit surprised that you claim that you function works on `"10 3"` - I would have expected this to give you an *no parse*  error

Comment: I do get a no parse error, although I thought that stemmed from the second input line and an end-of-file-related error.

Comment: no - it's because you try to read in two numbers at once - but you can use the `map read . words` I talked about - you can patternmatch as well if you like: `[x, y] <- map read . words <$> getLine` should do the trick here for the first line - you get the second (in a list) by just `numbers <- map read . words <$> getLine` (all in a `do` block of course!)

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to get the data shown here by:

```
readData :: IO (Int, [Int])
readData = do
    [nr, _] <- map read . words <$> getLine
    nrs     <- map read . words <$> getLine
    return (nr,nrs)
```

this will read both lines and return the `10` as the first component and `[1,4,8]` as the second component of a tuple if you read in your example

As the second number in the first line will just be the `length` of the returned list I skipped it here.

of course you probably will want to adapt this to your needs.